# Trying to get property of non-object in - Creating default object from empty value in

Tags: php, object, fetch

> PHP Notice:  Trying to get property of non-object in /public_html/classes/processor.php on line 11
> PHP Warning:  Creating default object from empty value in /public_html/classes/processor.php on line 13

How to fix these two without errors, file codes are below

```
 if ($today > $last->day) // Line 11
    {
        $last->time = $now;  // Line 13
        $last->day = $today;
        file_put_contents($GLOBALS['folder'] . 'data/last.json', json_encode($last));
        $repository = new Repository();
        $repository->openConnection();
        self::processDay($repository);
        self::processList($repository);
        $repository->closeConnection();
        return;
    }
```

Comment: Make sure that `$last` is the type of object you expect in your code.

Comment: You can either check if it [is an object](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.is-object) before or use the [null safe operator](https://wiki.php.net/rfc/nullsafe_operator) like `$last?->day`.

Comment: Can you edit and write the code? I don't know